# Pandas error in merging two files based on different number of columns (2 and 1) in 2 dataframes

Tags: python, pandas, merge

I have two files with the structures like below:

`df1`

```
intA,intB
4933401J01Rik,Gm37180
Gm37686,Gm37363
```

`df2`

```
chr,gene_type,gene_symbol
chr1,TEC,4933401J01Rik
chr2,TEC,Gm37180
chr3,TEC,Gm37363
chr4,TEC,Gm37686
```

I am trying to merge these two files. So basically I need to lift information from the `df2` for columns `intA` and `intB` in `df1`. In the final output, for each column of `df1` there should be two additional columns reporting the `chr` and `gene_type` based on the `df2`. The final output should look like:

result

```
intA,intB,chr,chr,gene_type,gene_type
4933401J01Rik,Gm37180,chr1,chr2,TEC,TEC
Gm37686,Gm37363,chr4,chr3,TEC,TEC
```

I run this code but it gives the error `Can only merge Series or DataFrame objects, a <class 'str'> was passed`.

```
df1 = pd.read_csv(df1)
df2 = pd.read_csv(df2)

   
result = pd.merge(df1, df2, how='left', left_on=['intA','intB'], right_on = ['gene_symbol'])

print(result)
```

Any help is appreciated - thank you.

Comment: I don't get the error you mention here - make sure you're not setting the values of df1 or df2 to something else before the call to pd.merge

Comment: Dear I do not have values but there are gene names that contain some numbers like: ```4933401J01Rik``` - I think the error can be because of this.

Comment: My Pandas verision 1.3.0 got the error running the code you tried:  `ValueError: len(right_on) must equal len(left_on)`    Seems it does not allow different numbers of columns (2 vs 1) on the 2 dataframes to merge on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it in an idiomatic / Pandas-ish way as follows:

As you are intending to merge contents of 2 columns (`intA`, `intB`) in `df1` with another dataframe `df2` and match only on one column (`gene_symbol`), you cannot directly merge them.  It is because the number of columns to match on are different.  The error `ValueError: len(right_on) must equal len(left_on)` would be resulted.

Instead, you have to transform the 2 columns `intA`, `intB` into one column with their contents in separate rows first before merging.

**1. Transform `df1` with `intA`, `intB` combined into one column with contents in separate rows:**

```
df1a = df1.copy()
df1a.columns = df1a.columns.str.split(r'(int)', expand=True)   # split column labels
df1a = df1a.droplevel(level=0, axis=1)
df1a = df1a.stack().rename_axis(index=['index', 'int_type']).reset_index()
```

**2. Merge on new column `int` (combined `intA` and `intB`) from `df1` and `gene_symbol` from `df2`:**

Now, we can merge on the same number of columns from the 2 dataframes:

```
df_merge = pd.merge(df1a, df2, how='left', left_on='int', right_on='gene_symbol')

# remove column 'gene_symbol' which has same duplicated info as 'int'
df_merge2 = df_merge.drop('gene_symbol', axis=1)
```

**3. Pivot to put `intA`, `intB` back to 2 separate columns:**

```
df_out = df_merge2.pivot(index='index', columns='int_type')

df_out.columns = df_out.columns.map(''.join)       # combine column labels
```

**Result:**

```
print(df_out)

                intA     intB  chrA  chrB gene_typeA gene_typeB
index                                                          
0      4933401J01Rik  Gm37180  chr1  chr2        TEC        TEC
1            Gm37686  Gm37363  chr4  chr3        TEC        TEC
```

Answer (score 0):

There's probably a more pandas-ish way to do this, but this will do what you want:

```
import pandas as pd

df1 = pd.read_csv('a')
df2 = pd.read_csv('b')

df3 = pd.DataFrame(columns=['intA', 'intB', 'chrA', 'chrB', 'gene_typeA', 'gene_typeB'])

for index, row in df1.iterrows():
    aMatch = df2.loc[df2['gene_symbol'] == row['intA']]
    bMatch = df2.loc[df2['gene_symbol'] == row['intB']]
    
    if aMatch.empty or bMatch.empty:
        # malformed data somehow
        print("malformed data")

    
    df3 = df3.append( { 'intA': row['intA'], 
                        'intB': row['intB'],
                        'chrA': aMatch['chr'].values[0], 
                        'chrB': bMatch['chr'].values[0],
                        'gene_typeA': aMatch['gene_type'].values[0],
                        'gene_typeB': bMatch['gene_type'].values[0]
                      }, ignore_index=True)
```

result:

```
            intA     intB  chrA  chrB gene_typeA gene_typeB
0  4933401J01Rik  Gm37180  chr1  chr2        TEC        TEC
1        Gm37686  Gm37363  chr4  chr3        TEC        TEC
```